# how to write htaccess and httpd.ini rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to write a rewrite rule to redirect a url:

So far I have attempted, but without success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^www\.domain\.com/product/catalog
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/new-product-page [L,R=301]
```

I am unsure what I may be doing wrong, or if the syntax is correct. I have the challenge of not being able to test this locally.

How can I write a simple rewrite rule to accomplish my goal of redirecting user to a new URL using .htacess syntax?

**UPDATE**

I ended up using just a RewriteRule, not a host condition.

```
RewriteRule ^/product/catalog/?$ /new-product-page [NC,R=301]
```

Then I edited my hosts file to test, and the redirect is working as I needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the domain against `HTTP_HOST` and the request path against `REQUEST_URI`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/catalog$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/new-product-page [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you Derek S. I also entered the solution I found useful for my problem.